# Operator '*' cannot be applied to 'int', 'java.lang.String'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

how to solve this problem error: bad operand types for binary operator '*' ?

this is my code :

```
  int minimal = (Integer.parseInt(TextUtils.isEmpty(listData.get(position).getMinimal()) ? "0" : listData.get(position).getMinimal()))
            *(TextUtils.isEmpty(listData.get(position).getQuantity()) ? "0" : listData.get(position).getQuantity());
```

this is the error : 
Error:(80, 17) error: bad operand types for binary operator '*'

first type:  int

second type: String

Can someone help me?
I'm new to android studio and this is my first time working with it.
Thanks in advance for your time. :)

Comment: Please don't write such convoluted code. It's too long to read, and it's too complex to understand. Extract into variables and you will find what the problem is.

Comment: Please format the code and share the complete error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second operand is still String . Do it this way.

```
 int minimal = Integer.parseInt(TextUtils.isEmpty(listData.get(position).getMinimal()) ? "0" : listData.get(position).getMinimal())
            *Integer.parseInt(TextUtils.isEmpty(listData.get(position).getQuantity()) ? "0" : listData.get(position).getQuantity());
```

its complex so you can simply use primitive variable can be readable easily.

```
int opA=Integer.parseInt(TextUtils.isEmpty(listData.get(position).getMinimal()) ? "0" : listData.get(position).getMinimal());
    int opB=Integer.parseInt(TextUtils.isEmpty(listData.get(position).getQuantity()) ? "0" : listData.get(position).getQuantity());
    int minimal=opA*opB;
```